# Frobenius Method, where does the log solution come from?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I've read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803788/method-of-frobenius-why-is-there-a-logartihmic-solution/2817504#2817504) which gets too involved for me, though I gathered that it involves differentiating $x^\alpha$ with respect to $\alpha$. Is there a simpler explanation (perhaps the "watered down version" referred to) of how the log term comes about?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4726785/617446